# Array of functions as a private property of onject

Tags: php, oop, anonymous-function

I would like to know the reason of "Unexpected T_FUNCTION" error in this php code:

```
class T
{
    private $array_of_functions = array(
        '0' => function() { return true; }
    );
}
```

Comment: First of all you're missing a semicolon `;` at the end of your `array()` definition.

Comment: Thanks, but problem is still topical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use such construction as default property value. Default [property value](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) can be only constant expression - so it can not contain closure definition since it's dynamic (i.e. evaluated when constructed at runtime). Instead you should initialize it inside class constructor:

```
class T
{
   private $array_of_functions = [];

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->array_of_functions = [
         function() { return true; }
      ];
   }
}
```

Comment: Should be `$this->array_of_functions`.